# Unsupported sampling flex/actionscript

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mxml, mxmlc

In action script i need

```
  Loading configuration file /opt/flex/frameworks/flex-config.xml
  t3.mxml(10): Error: unsupported sampling rate (24000Hz)

        [Embed(source="music.mp3")]

     t3.mxml(10): Error: Unable to transcode music.mp3.

        [Embed(source="music.mp3")]
```

The code is

```
         <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <!-- embed/EmbedSound.mxml -->
  <mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">

  <mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        import flash.media.*; 

        [Embed(source="sample.mp3")]
        [Bindable]
        public var sndCls:Class;

        public var snd:Sound = new sndCls() as Sound; 
        public var sndChannel:SoundChannel;

        public function playSound():void {
            sndChannel=snd.play();
        }   

        public function stopSound():void {
            sndChannel.stop();
        }   
    ]]>
</mx:Script>

<mx:HBox>
    <mx:Button label="play" click="playSound();"/>
    <mx:Button label="stop" click="stopSound();"/>
</mx:HBox>
</mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [livedocs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/UsingFlash/help.html?content=WSd60f23110762d6b883b18f10cb1fe1af6-7ce6.html):

> "Flash can import either 8- or 16-bit sounds at sample rates of 11, 22, or 44 kHz. Sounds recorded in formats that are not multiples of 11 kHz (such as 8, 32, or 96 kHz) are resampled when imported into Flash. Flash can convert sounds to lower sample rates on export."

Flex Builder will not do it for you so you need to downsample the "music.mp3" file to 22kHz manually before using it.

Edit:
I can't find proper documentation but [here](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/000/rb_r8.html) it says:

> "Sound Sample Rate - measured in Hz, this is fixed when the sound file is first recorded, and Flash .SWF files only allow four rates.
>
> The Flash SWF format has sampling rates of:
>
> 5500 Hz
>
> 11025 Hz
>
> 22050 Hz
>
> 44100 Hz (preferred setting)"

Comment: Ya thanks i converted my MP3 to 11025 Hz sampling rate and it then compiled

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the ID3v2 tag, and it should work.  I think it's the APIC.
So anyone who is facing problems embedding MP3 files, download ID3 Remover: http://sourceforge.net/projects/id3remover/files/id3remover/v1.2/ID3Remover_1_2.zip/download .